# Cast shatter on the other side of a wall

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, line-of-sight

I was wondering if you could cast *shatter* on the other side of a wall or on a point that you can't see. The spell description for *shatter* says that it is cast on a point that you choose. Other than that it does not say anything about how it's cast aside from it erupting from a point, so it seems there is no line involved.

**Would that also mean I can cast it in a room above me for example without even needing to see it?** It says that if you cast an AOE spell it comes onto the near side of that obstruction, is that based on a line from where you cast or where the spell originates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot.
Page 204 PHB: A CLEAR PATH TO THE TARGET

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it,
> so it can't be behind total cover.
> If you place an area of effect at a point that you can't
> see and an obstruction, such as a wall, is between you
> and that point, the point of origin comes into being on
> the near side of that obstruction.

Comment: We could say that after having cast _shatter_ on a wall there might no longer be a wall to block a clear path...
f(^_^)"